# Hibernate unsaved-value annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I would like to force Hibernate (4.2) checking object persistence by the field VERSION instead of the field ID. The xml below should work:

```
<id name="id" column="ID">
    <generator class="assigned" />
</id>
<version name="version" column="VERSION" unsaved-value="null" />
```

But I want to use annotations. Is this java code enough?

```
@Id
public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}

@Version
public Integer getVersion() {
    return this.version;
}
```

How to specify the unsaved-value tag? I don't find any annotation for this.
I've read somewhere, that Hibernate is smart enough to guess that an object is persistent or not, but it was not too convincing.
And what if I want to use -1 instead of null? There must be a way to achieve this, isn't it?

```
<version name="version" column="VERSION" unsaved-value="negative" />
```

Thanks for your help.

---

**Edited**. Hibernate 3.6 ref guide says:

> "The unsaved-value attribute is almost never needed in Hibernate3 and indeed has no corresponding element in annotations."

and

> "The assigned generator makes Hibernate use unsaved-value="undefined". This forces Hibernate to go to the database to determine if an instance is transient or detached, unless there is a version or timestamp property, or you define Interceptor.isUnsaved()."

I belive @Version will be sufficient for me.

Comment: take a look at this link
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html

Comment: @Khalil thank you for the link. Post updated. I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @Szmeby did you find anything?