# Spring Boot Hibernate loading but not saving data from an Event Listener

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am having problems when saving data from inside an event listener.

Currently I am listening for a AuthenticationSuccessEvent and the event is being called as expected (Checking with a logger).

I want to be able to use a JPA Repository inside the event and save data when the event has been triggered.

The repository is being initialized, data gets loaded from the database only the userRepository.save() doesnt work. I also dont get any exceptions during the saving.
The save() method works in other RestController without any problems.

(Database used is MySQL)

This is the listener class implementing the ApplicationListener interface:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class AuthenticationListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
    logger.info(userRepository.toString());
    String username = event.getAuthentication().getName();
    LoggedUser loggedUser = (LoggedUser) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    logger.info("Logged user: " + loggedUser);

    if (userRepository.existsByUsername(event.getAuthentication().getName())) {
        logger.info("Existing user: " + event.getAuthentication().getName());
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        user.setFirstname(loggedUser.getFirstName());
        user.setLastname(loggedUser.getLastName());
        logger.info("Saved: " + userRepository.save(user).toString());
    } else {
        logger.info("Not existing user: " + event.getAuthentication().getName());
        User user = new User(loggedUser.getFirstName(), loggedUser.getLastName(), "", username);
        logger.info(user.toString());
        logger.info("Saved: " + userRepository.save(user).toString());
    }
  }
}
```

UserRepository.java:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

  List<User> findAll();

  List<User> findByFirstname(String firstname);
  List<User> findByLastname(String lastname);
  List<User> findByFirstnameAndLastnameAndEmail(String firstname, String lastname, String email);

  User findByEmail(String email);   
  User findByUsername(String username);

  @Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(u) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email")
  boolean existsByEmail(@Param("email") String email);


  @Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(u) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username")
  boolean existsByUsername(@Param("username") String username);

}
```

Edit 1 (added logs around save point):

```
10:58:52.351 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/airpng]
10:58:52.404 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 0
10:58:52.405 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: 
10:58:52.978 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
10:58:52.979 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
10:58:52.979 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Committing Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
10:58:52.980 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - committing
10:58:52.982 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] after transaction
10:59:03.767 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO  a.p.a.shared.AuthenticationListener - Not existing user: bob
10:59:05.754 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO  a.p.a.shared.AuthenticationListener -  Firstname: Bob | Lastname: Hamilton | E-Mail: 
10:59:07.172 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.d.r.c.s.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'save' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
10:59:12.915 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
10:59:12.916 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Opened new Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for Hibernate transaction
10:59:12.916 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
10:59:12.916 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/airpng]
10:59:12.932 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - begin
10:59:12.933 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@38ba8070]
10:59:17.963 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Opening JPA EntityManager
10:59:17.964 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager
10:59:26.892 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
10:59:26.898 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
10:59:26.898 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Committing Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
10:59:26.899 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - committing
10:59:26.900 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] after transaction
```

Edit 2 (User entity added):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "USER_ID")

private long userId;
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(name = "USER_FIRSTNAME")
private String firstname;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(name = "USER_LASTNAME")
private String lastname;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 150)
@Column(name = "USER_USERNAME")
private String username;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 0, max = 150)
@Column(name = "USER_EMAIL")
private String email;

@Column(name = "USER_ACTIVE", nullable = false)
private boolean active;

@Autowired
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
@JsonBackReference
private List<Ownership> ownerships;

public User() {
}

public User(long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public User(String firstname, String lastname, String email, String username) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.email = email;
    this.username = username;
    this.active = true;
}

public User(String firstname, String lastname, String email) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.email = email;
    this.active = true;
}



public long getId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setId(long Id) {
    this.userId = Id;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}

public List<Ownership> getOwnerships() {
    return ownerships;
}

public void setOwnerships(List<Ownership> ownerships) {
    this.ownerships = ownerships;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return " Firstname: " + firstname + " | Lastname: " + lastname + " | E-Mail: " + email;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you turn on logging for org.springframework and org.hibernate and post your logs around the point of the save ?

Comment: hi there, here is the log (Edit 1)

Comment: Can you post your User entity source code ? From the debug line it looks like Hibernate thinks it has nothing to save. Maybe your entity mapping is wrong and isn't allowing Hibernate to work out a row needs adding ?

Is this of any use ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587844/hibernate-unsaved-value-annotation

Comment: I posted the user entity in the original post, I believe if mapping would be wrong then the saving wouldnt work anywhere, but it does work in the restcontroller

Comment: @R.Kozlica: Did you find any solution for this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @greenPadawan: did You find the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies within the fact that event listener runs in a different thread. And it looks like it needs an explicit transaction to save the entity.

```
Just annotate your method with @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```