# Spring boot data not saved from an event listener

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot project in which I am trying to save some data in a MySql table from inside and event listener.

I am using Spring boot **v1.5.10.RELEASE**, **JDK 1.8** and **MySql 5.7**

I have created a custom event (**`TestEvent`**) in my project, and the following async listener for this event.

```
@Component
public class TestListener implements ApplicationListener<TestEvent> {

    private TestService testService;

    @Autowired
    public JobCreatedListener(TestService testService) {
        this.testService = testService;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void onApplicationEvent(TestEvent applicationEvent) {
        testService.save(1L,"One");
    }
}
```

There is a **`TestService`** service class which is responsible for saving the data.

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityRepository testEntityRepository;

    @Transactional
    public TestEntity save(long id, String name) {        
            TestEntity entity = new TestEntity();
            entity.setId(id);
            entity.setName(name);
            return testEntityRepository.save(entity);        
    }

}
```

The problem which I am facing is that when this listener gets triggered, the method **`testService.save(1L,"One")`** executes successfully (without any errors or exception), but the data is not saved in the table.

However, when I call the same method from a controller, it executes successfully and the data is saved in the table.

I have tried annotating my method with **`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`**, but it doesn't make any difference either.

I am not sure what seems to be the problem. Any help is appreciated.

---

The entity and repository classes are as follows.

**`TestEntity`**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "testentity")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class TestEntity implements Serializable {

    private long id;

    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", length = 128)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**`TestEntityRepository`**

```
@Repository
public interface TestEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<TestEntity> {
}
```

Comment: whats the result if you simply remove all the ```@Transactional```?

Comment: when and what triggers your event?

Comment: @Barath: I tried that as well. Its the same result

Comment: @ScanQR: I am explicitly triggering the event using ApplicationEventPublisher

Comment: @greenPadawan its tricky can you share your full code to dig deeper. By any chance you set auto commit as false in application.properties or so ? share your properties too.

Comment: @Barath: That's pretty much the entire code relevant to this issue. I didn't set the auto commit to false. Also, had that been the issue, shouldn't it have not saved the data for controller as well?

Comment: I was doing some search and happen to come across this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111853/spring-boot-hibernate-loading-but-not-saving-data-from-an-event-listener I think this is the same problem.

Comment: I tried your case I couldnt find any issues at all [issue-repo](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/stackoverflow-issues/tree/master/stackoverflow-issue-56000941). I am able to see the insert statements. can you enable full logs and share it.

Answer (score 1):

try adding `@TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMPLETION)` to your handler method

```
    @TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMPLETION)
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void onApplicationEvent(TestEvent applicationEvent) {
        testService.save(1L,"One");
    }
```

Comment: `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

Try adding explicitly the transactionManager in `@Transactional` annotation. It could be the issue.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, value= YOUR_TXN_MANAGER)
```

Your `YOUR_TXN_MANAGER` must be same as of the one which is used when you are directly trying to call the same service from controller method.

Also add same definition on your repository.

```
@Transactional(value = YOUR_TXN_MANAGER)
@Repository
public interface TestEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<TestEntity> {
}
```